# Docker mysql: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, docker, containers

I am trying to connect to mysql server using mysql cli. Image was created using following command:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****** -d mysql
```

The docker container is **running**. `docker ps` prints:

```
johnd@john-pc:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
598c0f8680dc        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        3306/tcp, 33060/tcp    some-mysql
```

When i enter the following command:
`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root  -p` it returns:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

I also tried with `--protocol=tcp` attribute. How do i connect from client to mysql server running on docker using terminal from client machine (not from another docker)

EDIT: 
I also tried connecting to mysql using this command:

`docker run -it --rm mysql mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uexample-user -p`

It returns the same error

Comment: This is not a duplicate as i am using docker

Answer (score 3):

> mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root  -p

You are connecting to your localhost's sql server but you didn't map the docker's container port to the host.
Try mapping the port to your host by this:

> docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****** -d **-p 3306:3306** mysql

Then retry:

> mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p

Comment: You might need to add "--protocol=tcp" to the connect command.

Comment: I tried using this command `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root --protocol=tcp -p` but it returns the same error

Comment: Could you paste the output of `docker container ls` please?

Comment: Did you start the container using my command? Sql container take a while to start, try to use `docker logs some-mysql` to check its log to see what is going on

Answer (score 1):

same error to me, just remember start mysql service first in your container.

exec in your container

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Answer (score 0):

Using internal docker IP like 127.0.0.1 didn't work for me

I used my POD's IP and it worked

```
mysql -h 10.10.10.41 -P 3306 -u root -p
```

I still don't understand why I wasn't able to login and before and after this command I was able to login